# Photo Not Uploading on Check In Using Facebook iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api, uiimagepickercontroller, facebook-ios-sdk

So I'm creating an iPhone app that needs to be able to upload a photo when the user checks into a location using the Facebook Graph API.

Right now my code is this:

```
if (![delegate.facebook isSessionValid])
    [delegate.facebook authorize:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"offline_access", @"publish_checkins", nil]];

parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[placeDictionary objectForKey:@"id"] , @"place",
              serialisedCoordinates, @"coordinates",
              message, @"message",
              pickedImage, @"picture",
              @"Via the official REDACTED app", @"application", nil];

[delegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/checkins" andParams:parameters andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:fbCheckInResultHandler];
```

Where 'pickedImage' is the UIImage returned from a UIImagePickerController.

Even when I pick an image (i.e., pickedImage != nil), no picture is uploaded when checked in. The check in appears on Facebook with the message, coordinates and app information, just no image.

Really hope someone can help.

Cheers,
Kiran

Here is the whole function that is being called when a checkin is made:

```
-(void)fbPostCheckInWithMessage:(NSString *)message andFriends:(NSArray *)friends {

if (![delegate.facebook isSessionValid]) {
    NSLog(@"Session invalid");
    [delegate.facebook authorize:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", @"offline_access", @"publish_checkins", nil]];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Session valid");
}



NSMutableString *friendsIDString;
friendsIDString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[friends objectAtIndex:0] userID]];

if ([friends count] > 1) {
    for (User *f in taggedFriends) {
        if (f != [taggedFriends objectAtIndex:0]) {
            [friendsIDString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@", %@", f.userID]];
        }
    }
}

NSLog(@"Tagged Friends: %@", friendsIDString);
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [SBJSON new];

NSMutableDictionary *locationDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", userLocation.coordinate.latitude], @"latitude",
                                           [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", userLocation.coordinate.longitude], @"longitude", nil];

NSString *serialisedCoordinates = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:locationDictionary];

NSData *pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage);
NSLog(@"picture: %@", pictureData);

NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[placeDictionary objectForKey:@"id"] , @"place",
                      serialisedCoordinates, @"coordinates",
                      pictureData, @"message",
                      pickedImage, @"picture",
                      @"Via the official REDACTED app", @"application", nil];

[delegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/checkins" andParams:parameters andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:fbCheckInResultHandler];
}
```

I am using the friendsIDString to get the IDs of the friends the user with. I've removed this functionality from the example here because it was all commented out because I was trying to isolate what was causing the problem (which was the photo tagging). Just wanted to clear that up.

--UPDATE--
Here's how I'm setting pickedImage. I use the delegate methods from the UIImagePickerController:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    NSLog(@"Picked image");
    pickedImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    pickedImage = image;
   [imagePickerController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: how are you setting up pickedImage?

Comment: Just updated the question to include this.

Comment: Doesn't show the image in use - try a basic image setup in .h then pickedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithFrame etc. and see if it works with that?

Comment: That's exactly what I've done except I used [[UIImage alloc] init]; and then just set it equal to the image returned from the UIImagePickerController. I created a new app and it uploaded fine using the method I'm using here, so it must be some way I'm setting the app up. I'll keep searching and post something here if I find what was wrong.

Comment: the only thing i can think is to make sure all the necessary files are in the Compile Sources section, often the boxes that make it so become unticked by default and quick reactions mean you miss inclusion of a file..

Comment: Fixed it! I feel very foolish (but I guess that's how we all learn). It was a simple issue with permissions. I had a view controller that authorised the application _before_ the CheckInViewController and I hadn't included the 'user_photos" permissions there. Although this is completely my failing, it would've been nice for facebook to return a permissions error or something... odd. Thanks for your help, guys :D

Comment: Hey everyone, sorry to rekindled an old question, but it's still not working. I've managed to get it to upload a photo on its own but not with a checkin. I am completely at a loss about what to do. I would really appreciate it if @John or anyone else could create a really simple sample project that allows users to check in and upload a photo. I can't find help anywhere else. Thank you so much for your help so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload photos to facebook using :- UIImagePNGRepresentation,UIImageJPEGRepresentation,etc based on type of image or imagewithdata from UIImage class..

```
NSData *yourImageData= UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);
```

Initialize the dictionary :-

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictWithParam= [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Your text", @"message", yourImageWithData, @"theSource", nil];
```

finally send post :-

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos" andParams:mutableDictWithParam andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

In you app i think you have not initialized your NSData object(pickedimage) ..else everything seems fine.

As Per Our Discussion You can use this to compress image:-

```
NSData* UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage *image, CGFloat compressionQuality);
NSData *compressedImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourIMage, .5)//quality is ensured through second argument lies between o and 1
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working. Is there any way I can compress the size of the image?

Comment: Hold up, I seem to have misread your answer. Why am I sending the request to me/photos? I thought all requests for a checkin (including attached photos) were sent to me/checkins?

Comment: Still not working. The execution hangs for a considerable amount of time when trying to send the request. I've attached the whole method to my original question if anyone can see what's wrong I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Even with the compression the upload isn't working. The checkin works fine, just no photo.

Comment: This answer got it working for me having followed the Facebook SDK tutorial to add the functionality to the delegate, it's a pain, but I'd remove all the Facebook stuff in your implementation and try just the example here, then add the other functionality. My only problem is the message doesn't seem to be being attached with the code from this example.

Comment: Good luck...it's always best to go through api documentation and then implement the code ..:)

Comment: Oh also, this may be the problem btw, I had to change 'yourImageWithData' to the same as where you put 'yourImageData' to make it work - I didn't see the part of the docs which actually talked about posting but i probably missed it

Comment: @John, just followed your advice – Completely stripped the method and implemented the code in the solution. Unfortunately this didn't work. What are you guys' permissions for this? I'm using "publish_stream, user_photos and publish_checkins".

Comment: Further inspection shows that the request begins to load (ie., requesLoading is being called in the delegate class) but the request never finishes loading (i.e., request:DidLoad is never called in the delegate). Hope that is of some help.

Comment: I'm only using @"publish_stream", @"user_photos", nil]; so it's not that. are you getting any warnings? Definitely importing AppDelegate.h and connecting to it like so         AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; ?

Comment: i also authorise in the same action as uploading the photo, don't know if that's making the difference.

Comment: It's definitely exclusive to uploading photos because it works fine with regular checkins. I've also tried using the Facebook example app and photo uploading works fine on there, so it's definitely my app that has the problem.